# Magento 2: Predefine configuration values in config.php

Tags: magento2, system-config

I am trying to predefine the values for field in Configuration > Sales > Sales Email

I am not sure how to predefine it & check if it works.

Any thoughts ?

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What exactly do You mean? Do You want to create new email template. Or edit existing, or what?

Comment: Actually there is a backend settings 
see  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/6354227?key=b8036e07ca82c166506d9f654ea0c2ef

how can i set some email id in this through app/etc/config.php
so this field data can't be changes from backend

Comment: etc/config.xml will works only for new instance or for fields. If You need to change value for exising fields in Admin via code, use Install/Upgrade Scripts or DataPatches

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <YourSectionId>
            <YourGroupId>
                <fieldId>1</fieldId>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <page_type>0</page_type>
                <button_color>1979c3</button_color>
                <sign_color>fffcff</sign_color>
            </YourGroupId>
        </YourSectionId>
    </default>
</config>
```